How to optimize http requests to reduce time
I am creating a mobile application with Jetpack compose, I use Retrofit to make API calls but the API requests take on average ~350ms for ~230kB size
It's an API to which I don't have server-side access, but I thought there were some good practices to reduce query time, for example not retrieving fields that we don't use?
Any welcome and recommandations are welcome!
My actually code:
val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
val converter = json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType())
            
val chuckerInterceptor = ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(androidApplication())
  .collector(ChuckerCollector(androidApplication()))
  .maxContentLength(250000L)
  .redactHeaders(emptySet())
  .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
  .build()

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
  .build()

Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl("https://api.exemple.com")
  .addConverterFactory(converter)
  .client(client)
  .build()


"for example not retrieving fields that we don't use" -- the server controls what data it sends back for a request, not the client. So, contact those who maintain the server and ask if they have more-optimized calls that you can make. For example, perhaps there are query parameters that you can use to trim the result set. "the API requests take on average ~350ms for ~230kB size" -- that does not seem particularly bad for a Web service request, particularly for a response of that size.

@CommonsWare: I guess nothing more can be added to what you already wrote. Does that suffice as an answer? Should the question be closed instead?

@Leviathan: "I guess nothing more can be added to what you already wrote" -- somebody might come up with something!  "Does that suffice as an answer?" -- for the past few years, I only answer when I can say something definitive. This sort of question does not lend itself well to a definitive answer IMHO. "Should the question be closed instead?" -- that was not my initial reaction, but I would not argue if people cast close votes.

I feel you covered the topic in its entirety, but let's see if anyone will come up with something else. We can always close the question later on. :)
